# Facebook Android SDK 4.x LoginManager.logout() doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook

I call `LoginManager's` logout method. I see in `logout()` method's implementation that `AccessToken` was set to null, current profile is set to null, express login set to false. But what I noticed, by setting break points inside the `Facebook SDK` is that it wants to do a local broadcast of the token and profile having changed, but then I set a breakpoint where it should have received the broadcast and the breakpoint never trips.

I followed the instruction on how to setup the `Manifest`. I don't believe I've done anything incorrectly. I see a lot of old comment talking about calling `FacebookSDK.SDKInitialize()` but that's old documentation as `sdkInitialize` is deprecated and should be automatically called for you by the `SDK` already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using GraphRequest to take away permssion by DELETE of /me/permission get me to the point where on next launch of the app, facebook will ask if user wants to login as . You have to go to the device's Account in Settings to delete the facebook account before it'll let you login as another user.